# Trying to combine the sums of a filter into one cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-query-language

```
=filter(K24:K29,H24:H29="buy") / filter(I24:I29,H24:H29="buy")
```

Currently it outputs multiple matches separately like below:

```
               (1000)  /  (100)
               (400)   /  (100)
```

I would like to combine the sums into one cell like this:

```
               (1400)  /  (200)
```

I thought =SUMIF would do it but getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={SUM(FILTER(K24:K29, H24:H29="buy")), SUM(FILTER(I24:I29, H24:H29="buy"))}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly.